# Awk command field separator

Tags: awk, grep

I want print only port number 8443, using below command but unfortunately my command was not helping me to print only port number.

```
$ netstat -tupln | grep '8443' |  awk --field-separator=":" '{print $2}'
  8443            0.0.0.0
```

Can you please some one help me on this?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/350025/ideas-for-parsing-netstat-results-for-active-connections

Comment: Does "grep -o 8443" meet your need? Might be easier, depending on which OS you are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a pattern as your field separator:

```
netstat -tupln | awk -F '[ :]+' '/8443/{print $5}'
```